spring webflux r2dbc with custom aop is not working
I'm using aop on springr2dbc webflux and when I use @Transactional and custom AOP, I'm experiencing an issue where aspect doesn't apply if I don't specify order in the aspect of custom AOP.
I am using spring aop and r2dbc.
By the way, if you use @transactional and the aop I made, only transactional is applied.
When spring aop and jpa were used, when additional aop was applied by attaching @transactional and @Logging annotations to one method, transactional was performed first, and then aop applied to logging annotation worked.
@Target(CLASS, FUNCTION, ANNOTATION_CLASS, TYPE)
@Inherited
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Logging()


@Service
class SampleService(
    private val memberRepository: MemberRepository,
    private val teamRepository: TeamRepository,
) {

    @Transactional
    @Logging
    fun testServiceMethod() {
        val team = Team(name = "team").apply {
            addMembers(listOf(Member(name = "member1"), Member(name = "member2")))
        }

        teamRepository.save(team)
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
class LoggingAspect(
    private val sampleService: SampleService,
) {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Around("@annotation(com.example.kotlinjpaquerydsl.aop.Logging)")
    fun suspendCallLogging(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {
        sampleService.testCallMethod()
        val proceed = joinPoint.proceed()
        sampleService.testCallMethod()
        return proceed
    }
}

By the way, when using spring aop and r2dbc, only @Transactional is applied, and the aop I applied is not working.
@Service
class TeamService(
    private val teamRepository: TeamRepository,
) {

    @Logging
    @Transactional
    suspend fun createTeam(request: CreateTeamRequest): Team {
        return teamRepository.save(
            with(request) {
                Team(
                    name = name,
                    registeredBy = requestedBy,
                    modifiedBy = requestedBy
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
class LoggingAspect(
    private val teamService: TeamService,
) {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Around("@annotation(com.example.coroutineaop.aop.Logging)")
    fun suspendCallLogging(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any? {

        return joinPoint.runCoroutine {
         
           teamService.getAll()
         
            val result = joinPoint.proceedCoroutine().let { result ->
                if (result is Mono<*>) {
                    result.awaitSingleOrNull()
                } else {
                    result
                }
            }

            teamService.getAll()
            result
        }
    }
}

If I give an order to aop, the custom advisor will work first, so why does it work normally, but if i don't give an order doesn't work.
